# nested ifelse not displaying the right output based on the range criteria

Tags: php, date, if-statement

Right, probably an easy one, but im having a blond moment and scratching my head.

```
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London'); 
    $today = date('d-m');

            if(($today >= '01-11') && ($today <= '20-11')) 
                { 
                    echo "<p class='rememberance'>&nbsp;</p>";
                }
            elseif (($today >= '2-12') && ($today <= '25-12')) 
                {
                    echo "<p class='christmas'>&nbsp;</p>";
                }
            elseif (($today >= '01-01') && ($today <= '09-01')) 
                {
                    echo "<p class='new-year'>&nbsp;</p>";
                }
            elseif (($today >= '01-04') && ($today <= '19-04')) 
                {
                    echo "<p class='easter'>&nbsp;</p>";
                }
            elseif (($today >= '01-06') && ($today <= '19-07')) 
                {
                    echo "<p class='yearend'>&nbsp;</p>";
                }
            else
                {
                echo "<p class='normal'>&nbsp;</p>";
                }
```

I have some CSS rules set to display a little image based on the banding that the php outputs, now currently it is only showing the rememberance class! Can anyone help!!? Cheers

Comment: How are you expecting the comparison to work?  You are performing a string comparison here, not a day\month comparison.

Comment: Invert the order of day-month to month-day and fix typos e.g. `02` instead of `2`

Comment: [Please don't repost the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59283366/nested-ifelse-error-on-values-between-a-given-range).

Comment: Sorry, i was confused as i looked like my original post had been closed. Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to build a calculation with a string. "Lager than" or "smaller than" would not work this way. You need to remove the minus and do that stuff with integer values. Also you need to switch the month and the day for that...

Try `md` and then do it like

```
$today = date('md');
if(($today >= 1101) && ($today <= 1120))
```